# Creating Drupal widgets with selenium automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drupal

I want to create with selenium webdriver a Drupal's widget given some data (texts, images, ...)

I managed to open the back office of a website build on a Drupal solution, but I stuck on trying to make the button "add widget" work :

I have something like :

```
# id of the button "Ajouter widget" (add widget)
id_add_widget = 'edit-field-content-add-more-add-modal-form-area-add-more'

widget_button = driver.find_element_by_id(id_add_widget)
widget_button.click()
```

corresponding to the following state :
[image: add widget button]
but it fails to launch the choices of widgets that you would get by clicking on it :
[image: list widget]
(and now, I need to choose amongst this liste...)

Answer (score 0):

Is this id `edit-field-content-add-more-add-modal-form-area-add-more` unique in `HTML DOM ?`

If Yes, then try below code trials :

**Code 1 :**

```
widget_button = driver.find_element_by_id(id_add_widget)
widget_button.click()
```

**Code 2:**

```
widget_button = driver.find_element_by_id(id_add_widget)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code 3:**

Use `Explicit waits`

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "edit-field-content-add-more-add-modal-form-area-add-more"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If this `ID` is not `unique in HTML DOM` then, You'd have to look for different locator.